# How to get total / sum before first row in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Please help me, I need output total on top of data shown...

I have Looping like this in my blade.php

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($datas $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->amount }}</td>
            </tr> 
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

and output will like this:

[image]

And now how to get output total before firs row like image below?

[image]

Comment: did you fetch the total from sql query?

Comment: Is the heading (Total Pencil) to be generated or hard coded?

Comment: sounds like an exciting assignment

Comment: @NigelRen it will be generated

Comment: Please can you show the code your using to populate `$datas` i.e. controller/route code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The laravel `collection` has an inbuilt function called `sum` which returns the sum of Collection.

[Learn here about collection function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum)

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Pencil</td>
            <td>{{ $datas->sum('amount') }}</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach($datas $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->amount }}</td>
            </tr> 
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Is collection sum able to sum by key? for example i have group pencil and pen, so it will be separate total by their group

Comment: yes you can but with `groupBy` as per product type field

Comment: can you give me some reference sir? i have no idea for blade file..

Comment: sure but before i want your table structure...or model

Answer (score 3):

convert object to array

```
$datasArray = json_decode(json_encode($datas), true);
```

collect all **'amount'** in an array

```
$amountArray = array_column($datasArray,'amount');
```

Sum all element of **$amountArray**

```
$total = array_sum($amountArray );
```

print **$total** where you want